# Getting multiple values for checkboxes with dynamic data react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, axios, state

*Get All values of checkboxes from dynamic values*

```
import * as React from "react";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import axios from "axios";

export default function Checkboxes() {
const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([]);

const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = React.useState(() =>
users.map((i) => false)
);

React.useEffect(() => {
getUsers();
}, []);
const getUsers = async () => {
 try {
  const response = await axios.get(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
  );
  setUsers(response.data);
 } catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
 }
 };

  const isCheckboxChecked = (index, checked) => {
  setIsChecked((isChecked) => {
  return isChecked.map((c, i) => {
    if (i === index) return checked;
    return c;
  });
  });
  };
  console.log(isChecked);

 return (
 <div>
  {users.map((checkbox, index) => {
    return (
      <FormControlLabel
        key={index}
        control={
          <Checkbox
            checked={isChecked[index]}
            onChange={(e) => isCheckboxChecked(index, e.target.checked)}
          />
        }
        label={checkbox.name}
      />
    );
   })}
   <pre>{JSON.stringify(isChecked, null, 4)}</pre>
   </div>
   );
   }
```

i'm trying to do like this.
https://codesandbox.io/s/69640376-material-ui-react-multiple-checkbox-using-tabs-8jogw?file=/demo.js
but this has static data.

this is what i have done so far
https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-euclid-w3dzpq?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your code and found that you should issue in your "isCheckboxChecked" method.

```
const isCheckboxChecked = (index, checked) => {
    isChecked[index] = checked;
    setIsChecked([...isChecked]);
};
```

Another issue was you should wait till you get your response from API, so we are only setting checkboxes when we have users.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (users.length) setIsChecked(users.map((i) => false));
}, [users]);
```

Hope this helps

I've already updated your sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-euclid-w3dzpq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: what should be the state of const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState() ???

Comment: Hey @razer it should be [] (an empty array) as it will get updated in useEffect

Answer (score 0):

If you need the same functionality as the first sandbox, then you need to update somehow your "checked" array after you fetch the users.

Currently this array is not updated, so you never see true/false values

Try this

```
  const getUsers = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
      );
      await setUsers(response.data);
      setIsChecked(() => response.data.map((i) => false));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-paper-sguor0)

If you don't want to use a function, you can instead use an array

```
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, []);
  const getUsers = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
      );
      await setUsers(response.data);
      setIsChecked(Array.from({length: response.data.length}, i => i = false))
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

In order to clear the "uncontrolled state" warnings/errors, change this line

```
          <Checkbox
            checked={isChecked[index] == null  ? false : isChecked[index]}
            onChange={(e) => isCheckboxChecked(index, e.target.checked)}
          />
```

Checkbox must have an initial controlled state of true or false and not null/undefined.

Comment: what should be the state of 
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState()  ???

Comment: @razer check my updated answer. i had forgotten to save my edits in my sandbox.

Comment: sorry to bother you again but i'm still getting errors of uncontrolled state. and its returning empty but sometimes it work

Comment: @razer i have updated my answer in order to fix this error.